# Wow Cataclysm Leveling: Max DPS Warrior spec

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm creating a warrior to play in a group with 4 friends (will be playing as a dps).  I have the 2 handed heirloom axe so I'm looking at arms specs.  What is a high damage (dps) spec for leveling arms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For leveling I suggest that you develop your own spec. Just take whatever you think will be fun. Max DPS is a non-issue - or at least should be. If you will start raiding with that toon, get a raiding spec and adjust it - just so that you can start developing a feel for it.

Comment: +1, get a decent build (either use common sense or look something up on wowwiki) and just have fun while playing with friends. I doubt anyone will bother too much with maxing dps while leveling. For raiding though, thats a completely different story.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer twice if I could.